# run swpier js with webpack

Tags: webpack, swiper.js

I still can not see the dots under the slider and the arrows not functional. could you please help.
webpack has one entry entry.js contains the following

```
import 'normalize.css';
import '../sass/style.scss';
import '../sass/login.scss';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
import './swiper.js';
```

and the swiper.js

```
import Swiper from 'swiper';

var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 15,
    autoplay: true,
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
  
// Responsive breakpoints
breakpoints: {
    // when window width is >= 320px
    320: {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: 20
    },
    // when window width is >= 480px
    480: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 30
    },
    // when window width is >= 640px
    640: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 40
    },
// when window width is >= 800px
    800: {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 30
    }
  }
  }
  );
```

I use babel as well, but tried everything did not solve it